# How can I specify UTC to Pandas.read_sql

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pandas

I have a SQL Server table that has dates with are UTC.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [utcDT] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Rate] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

utcDT                       Rate
-------------------------------------
2012-05-30 20:07:00.0000000 1.237025
2013-09-02 10:55:00.0000000 1.322
2011-06-10 18:46:00.0000000 1.434335
2013-06-13 20:55:00.0000000 1.33736
2016-01-08 04:13:00.0000000 1.088215
```

Query:

```
sql_query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MyTable] WHERE [utcDT} >= '2020-01-01'"
connection = pyodbc.connect(connection__DATA)
data = pd.read_sql(sql_query, connection,index_col='utcDT',parse_dates=True)
    print(data.index)
    print(data.dtypes)
    print(data.info())

DatetimeIndex(['2020-11-06 21:07:00', '2020-11-06 21:08:00',
               '2020-11-06 21:09:00', '2020-11-06 21:10:00',
               '2020-11-06 21:11:00', '2020-11-06 21:12:00',
               '2020-11-06 21:13:00', '2020-11-06 21:14:00',
               '2020-11-06 21:15:00', '2020-11-06 21:16:00',
               ...
               '2020-11-17 23:50:00', '2020-11-17 23:51:00',
               '2020-11-17 23:52:00', '2020-11-17 23:53:00',
               '2020-11-17 23:54:00', '2020-11-17 23:55:00',
               '2020-11-17 23:56:00', '2020-11-17 23:57:00',
               '2020-11-17 23:58:00', '2020-11-17 23:59:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='utcDT', length=10000, freq=None)
Rate    float64
dtype: object
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 10000 entries, 2020-11-06 21:07:00 to 2020-11-17 23:59:00
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   Rate  10000 non-null  float64
dtypes: float64(1)
```

How can I ensure that pandas reads these in as UTC?

Comment: If you need to be time zone aware then don't use `datetime` or `datetime2` column types, use `datetimeoffset` with a 0 offset for UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Why not read the data as Pandas does and then do some quick cleaning to get what you want? Just create a new column so that your date-time objects are timezone aware.

Your output is somewhat confusing, so I cannot tell if `data['utcDT']` is a DatetimeIndex or a standard series with datetime objects. In any case, you want to use `tz_localize()` ([see the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_localize.html)).

If it is a DatetimeIndex, then

```
data["utcDTtz"] = data["utcDT"].tz_localize(tz="UTC")
```

or else if just datetime objects, then

```
data["utcDTtz"] = data["utcDT"].dt.tz_localize(tz="UTC")
```